# How to paste regular text from Microsoft Onenote to Evernote

Tags: copy-paste, microsoft-onenote, evernote

Using Onenote 2013 and Evernote, when I try copy pasting from Onenote to Evernote I get notes pasted as images instead of text.

One workaround is to paste into Microsoft Word, and then copy and paste to Evernote.

Is there a direct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those suffering with this, there is a partial workaround, for pasting only text (loses formatting).

I use an AutoHotKey script for this. Good thing is it works in any program, not only Evernote.

Script below, adapted from [this forum post](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/10412-paste-plain-text-and-copycut/).

Autohotkey - http://autohotkey.com

```
$^+v::
  Sleep, 100
  ClipSaved := ClipboardAll  ;save original clipboard contents
  Clipboard = %clipboard%  ;remove formatting
  Sleep, 100
  Send   ^v  ;send the Ctrl+V command
  Sleep, 100
  Clipboard := ClipSaved  ;restore the original clipboard contents
  ClipSaved =  ;clear the variable
Return
```

Comment: The disadvantage is that is also removes the formatting if you are copy-pasting from/to applications like Word, where you might want to preserve the formatting ... Still, a nice solution

Comment: Oh and, if the script doesn't work, try the minor modification here: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/49393-clipboard-format-removal-doesnt-work/

Answer (score 2):

From experimentation, this works for me:

When you copy from OneNote, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.   Then when you paste to Evernote, use
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (don't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).  You will be shown options from the clipboard.
 Then simply hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Update: When I originally posted this, I didn't realize that I could do this because of a freeware program I had downloaded called PhraseExpress.

Comment: For me, Ctrl + Alt +V creates a new note in evernote with clipboard content. Both if I'm in an evernote window or another program.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the other answers using AutoHotkey to tackle this issue, I've created a AutoHotkey script that changes the Ctrl-C command to remove the formatting when copying text *from* OneNote. This avoids copy-paste of formatting/images/files from breaking in other applications.

```
$^c::
Send ^c ; Do a normal copy to clipboard
sleep 100 ; Wait for the copy to finish
WinGet current_application, ProcessName, A ; Get the name of the current application

; if the application is OneNote, and the copied content is text ...
if ((current_application = "ONENOTE.EXE") && DllCall("IsClipboardFormatAvailable", "uint", 1)) {
    clipboard = %clipboard% ; remove the formatting
}
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to Pasting into Notebook then CNP from Notepad to EN.

Not smooth, but it worked :-/

This is on the latest EN release on Win7 and OneNote 2010.

Comment: This is the same approach the OP is trying to avoid, only using Notepad as the intermediate app rather than Word, so it isn't really a solution to the question.

Answer (score -1):

I just found a third-party solution to this issue.  The clipboard manager "Clipboard Fusion" has a standard "scrub" feature which allows OneNote clips to be pasted as plain text.  This is a partial solution but I still needed to manually re-instate any necessary text formatting.
I contacted technical support and they have just provided me with a macro which enables me to paste fully formatted text! I have not tested it on complex formatting (tables etc) but it certainly transfers basic fonts and styles.

Comment: Should the macro you're using be part of your answer?  It's not much help without it!